# Count Unique Values Throughout One Day For Nonconsecutive Student ID's

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql, analytics, sqlhelper

I am trying to figure out how to count all instances where a student is online without counting duplicate instances.

For example, in the screenshot below, I want to see a column counting only instances where a student is logged in. So, if Student A is logged in at 5 AM, count = 1. Student B logged in at 7, Count = 2. At some point student A logged off and logged back on at 8 am, the count should be 2, not 3.

Thank you!

| Student | Time. | **Desired Column (Count)** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 AM | 1 |
| B | 7 AM | 2 |
| A | 8 AM | 2 |
| C | 9 AM | 3 |
| D | 10 AM | 4 |
| E | 11 AM | 5 |
| D | 12 PM | 5 |

I am mainly trying to track the activity and only count when someone is logged in. If those students appear multiple times, we can assume they logged off at some point and logged back in. It's basically a unique running count. Not sure how to write this in SQL. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please don't add images or links. Show both sample data and expected outcome as tables with text here in your question. Or provide a fiddle link.

Comment: What is the data type of the Time column?

Comment: @ahmed, these at timestamps. I am basically extracting time as text. 

Time Examples:
5:00:00 AM
7:04:00 AM
8:00:00 AM
10:00:00 AM
11:26:00 AM
11:29:00 AM
1:00:00 PM
1:00:00 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, use the exists operator with a correlated subquery to check if the student has logged in before:

```
SELECT Student, Time_,
  SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY  Time_) AS expected_count
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    CASE
     WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name D WHERE D.Student = T.Student AND D.Time_<T.Time_)
     THEN 0 ELSE 1
    END AS flag
  FROM table_name T
) D
ORDER BY Time_
```

[See demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jho2wKRA)

Comment: Expected count is returning 0 for every student. Doesn’t seem to return the expected.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in a fiddle like this https://dbfiddle.uk/Jho2wKRA

Comment: I’m using HIVE so the exist clause was the issue.thanks it works now